# Pass one of the list field value to pagename attribute for a apex:include tag

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I have a picklist in my custom object. I am creating a visualforce page where different templates need to be embedded. In main VF page, I am iterating this custom object list, where in I have to pass picklist value to this apex:include's attribute "pagename". And I have visualforce pages whose name is same as this pick list value.

Below is the sample codes that I have tried so far but had no luck :

Code 1 --

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf" controller="MyCheckLayoutController">

 <apex:repeat value="{!listwrapper}"  var="cl" >  
        <apex:include pageName="{!cl.check_layout_type}" >     // cl.check_layout_type is variable in wrapper class and it is the name of visualforce page as well.

/*  This gives error as variable not found.  */

        </apex:include>
    </apex:repeat>
 </apex:page>
```

Code 2 --

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf" controller="MyCheckLayoutController">

 <apex:repeat value="{!listwrapper}"  var="cl" >  

   <apex:variable var="type" value="{!cl.check_layout_type}" />
    {!type}  // This variable contains value

   <apex:include pageName="{!type}" > 

/* But It doesnot read it's value here. It says pagename cannot be null*/
        </apex:include>
    </apex:repeat>
 </apex:page>
```

I have tried many ways till now. It would be really great help if some one could answer.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So I actually gave this a try and it looks like the page name needs to be defined in the VF page or must be bound to a getter that return a page ref or a property that has get attribute that returns a page ref.  It looks like it cannot be bound to the variable in a repeater.  Maybe you should try to see if [Dynamic Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_components_implementation.htm) might do the trick

Comment: I have tried this option also. But how do I change the variable  SelectedOptionWithNameOfPage while iterating a list without any call to controller? As far as I know, we cannot call any apex function in repeat tag. And, since my VF page is rendered as pdf, I can not call JavaScript function there. Is there any alternative of how can I change an apex variable on iteration of a list ?

Comment: I would first remove the renderAs and see what happens.  If the page displays properly, then it's the rendering as pdf.